# How do I make queries faster on a long single document in mongoDB that uses the bucket pattern?

Tags: python, mongodb

So I collected prices of bitcoin from most of the past year into a single document using the bucket pattern in mongoDB. The data looks like this...

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("612b4f770afc1d9f18d7b4bd"),
    "BTC" : [
        {
            "count" : 1,
            "price" : 10263.8
        },
        {
            "count" : 2,
            "price" : 10270.84
        },
        {
            "count" : 3,
            "price" : 10267.62
```

etc... the total count is 435,164  at which point the max amount of data for a single document was reached. Each increment in count represents moving forward one minute in time. When I attempt to loop through the data using this:

```
  for x in range(0,100):
    price = db.historical_data.find({},{"_id":0})[0]['BTC'][x]['price']

    print(price)
```

the output is horrendously slow...around 2 results per second... most latency issues in mongoDB that I can find tend to center around indexing documents and/or using a pattern like the one I've already used, so I'm a little at a loss to explain this.

The 'problem' I'm trying to solve here is how to run a program like the following, which creates a ledger based on different parameters in a trading strategy...

```
from db_connection import *
from db_functions import *
from coinbase_websocket import *


def on_message(ws, message):
  
  info =json.loads(message)


  for A in range(1,10):
    for a in range(2,5):
      for e in range(1,20):
         
          #HERE IS THE TRADING ALGORITHM (REMOVED BY REQUEST...) . It  loops through different parameters whereby ledgers are created  giving hypothetical (or actual, if API is inserted...) trades, and  the profits. I used this method to construct databases and then take  max profit values to determine which parameters to use in real  trades...
```

The results look like this...

```
        {

            "count" : 1,

            "buy_sell" : "buy",

            "price" : 47668,

            "amount" : 300,

            "BTC" : 0.006288810103213896,

            "profit" : 0,

            "increase" : 0,

            "decrease" : 0,

            "time" : "2021-08-13T21:09:43.472662Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 2,

            "buy_sell" : "sell",

            "price" : 46380.62,

            "amount" : 291.4601524655875,

            "BTC" : 0.006288810103213896,

            "profit" : -8.539847534412502,

            "increase" : 0,

            "decrease" : 1,

            "time" : "2021-08-14T10:52:12.715998Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 3,

            "buy_sell" : "buy",

            "price" : 46380.62,

            "amount" : 600,

            "BTC" : 0.0129364376759086,

            "profit" : "no change",

            "increase" : 0,

            "decrease" : 1,

            "time" : "2021-08-14T10:52:12.715998Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 4,

            "buy_sell" : "sell",

            "price" : 47633.92,

            "amount" : 615.7510774112118,

            "BTC" : 0.0129364376759086,

            "profit" : 7.21122987679928,

            "increase" : 1,

            "decrease" : 0,

            "time" : "2021-08-16T00:17:22.332923Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 5,

            "buy_sell" : "buy",

            "price" : 47633.92,

            "amount" : 300,

            "BTC" : 0.006298032998333961,

            "profit" : "no change",

            "increase" : 1,

            "decrease" : 0,

            "time" : "2021-08-16T00:17:22.332923Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 6,

            "buy_sell" : "sell",

            "price" : 46347.5,

            "amount" : 291.67916082699054,

            "BTC" : 0.006298032998333961,

            "profit" : -1.1096092962101807,

            "increase" : 0,

            "decrease" : 1,

            "time" : "2021-08-16T13:53:08.939129Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 7,

            "buy_sell" : "buy",

            "price" : 46347.5,

            "amount" : 600,

            "BTC" : 0.01294568207562436,

            "profit" : "no change",

            "increase" : 0,

            "decrease" : 1,

            "time" : "2021-08-16T13:53:08.939129Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 8,

            "buy_sell" : "sell",

            "price" : 44905.63,

            "amount" : 580.8980088785802,

            "BTC" : 0.01294568207562436,

            "profit" : -20.211600417630052,

            "increase" : 0,

            "decrease" : 2,

            "time" : "2021-08-17T21:38:27.207353Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 9,

            "buy_sell" : "buy",

            "price" : 44905.63,

            "amount" : 1200,

            "BTC" : 0.02672270715275568,

            "profit" : "no change",

            "increase" : 0,

            "decrease" : 2,

            "time" : "2021-08-17T21:38:27.207353Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 10,

            "buy_sell" : "sell",

            "price" : 46545.43,

            "amount" : 1242.887030267697,

            "BTC" : 0.02672270715275568,

            "profit" : 22.67542985006685,

            "increase" : 1,

            "decrease" : 0,

            "time" : "2021-08-19T21:32:45.749672Z"

        },

        {

            "count" : 11,

            "buy_sell" : "buy",

            "price" : 46545.43,

            "amount" : 300,

            "BTC" : 0.006445315898897056,

            "profit" : "no change",

            "increase" : 1,

            "decrease" : 0,

            "time" : "2021-08-19T21:32:45.749672Z"

        }

    ]
```

As you can see, this risk managing strategy turned a profit even as BTC went down around 1k per "coin". The algorithm is based off some math (needs to be updated) I've posted on dontfakethefunkonanastydunk.com.

So, ideally, I want to back-test over the historical values of bitcoin in a similar way, only using values from my database instead of the websocket feed...

UPDATE: The issue can be fixed somewhat simply by making the size of the document smaller. By limiting the number of prices in a single document to 10,000 for example, and using the find method in the beginning of this post. I'm able to index through these prices at a rate of about 400/second, which isn't ideal, but still provides a "work-around".

UPDATE** Switching to MYSQL for the iteration process seems to be the best play, although the flexibility of schema in mongo is nice for creating ledgers. I will simply marry the two for this project.

Comment: I'm of the mind that there may be some reasonable limit to the size each document should be????? I might go ahead and make this into a collection of documents, but I wonder how large I should make each one? (... or equivalently, how many documents to make...)

Comment: Please don't paste your entire application. Provide the input data and expected result and maybe explain how to get such results.

Comment: The input data is real time price data via the coinbase websocket feed that has been collected in the database as 'price'. I've taken out the code for constructing the database (which I do at the same time I make trades for various reasons...) , and just shown the results. Hope that helps.

Comment: In other words, I need to be able to look for specific price increases/decreases over linear time. I was able to accomplish this simply previously simply by receiving real time data from an exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The max. size of a document in MongoDB is 16MiByte, it's a fix limit you cannot change.

If you like to print only the price, the simply run

```
db.collection.find({}, { price: "$BTC.price" })
```

If you like to get only the first 100 prices, use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { price: { $slice: ["$BTC.price", 0, 100] } } }
])
```

In order to get the actual size of each document (which must be smaller than 16'777'216) use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { size: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } } }
])
```

Comment: Vielen Dank Wernfried:) If I use db.historical_data.aggregate([{ $project: { price: { $slice: ["$BTC.price", 0, 435164] } } }]).pretty()  I do print out these prices super fast!  I still need to be able to loop through these values in order to solve my problem though. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Would be difficult without knowing your problem. Operators [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#mongodb-expression-exp.-map) or [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#mongodb-expression-exp.-reduce) or [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/#mongodb-expression-exp.-range) may help

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted the specifics of my problem at the bottom of my question. Let me know if there's anything else I can be more specific about.